# How do I connect an HTTP trigger azure function to my azure logic app solely using the Logic App HTTP action?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, openapi, azure-api-management

I have a http trigger azure function where the user posts data into the following parameters within the function's URL, {sourceContainer}/{sourceFilename}/{destContainer}/{destFolder}. The function starts when it receives this post request of the url and it unzips the files content and then places it in a blob. I am trying to have a logic app that calls this function. Azure docs says that since I have a custom route that I need to define an OpenAPI defintion.

So in addition to defining an OpenAPI (I have a separate stackoverflow question concerning that method), I wish to  try the approach of calling my Azure function by plugging its function URL into a Logic App HTTP POST action as demonstrated here http://www.mattruma.com/call-a-secure-azure-function-from-a-logic-app/. But as mention before I have multiple parameters that need to be filled out for my function URL and there is only one available query input. How can I make it so there is multiple query inputs to match my amount of parameters or am I suppose to plug my parameters as a json body in the body section of the HTTP action. I am in need of precise direction as I am very unfamiliar with this method and there is not much documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple query, append this after the url:

```
?A=a&B=b&C=c&D=d
```

In Logic App's HGttp action, you could format the query parameters as a json body like this:

```
{
    "A":"a",
    "B":"b",
    "C":"c",
    "D":"d"
}
```

Comment: If I got misunderstand of you, please let me know, @Dimeji Olayinka. As for" function appears for a half a second and then disappears" you comment on the deleted question, have you found a solution? If yes, please let me know, too.